# Storing additional information about the user

Tags: users, profiles

I'm creating a recruitment website in wordpress and need a way to store details about the user such as previous experience and qualifications. I want the user to be able to edit this information as soon as they have registered an account (not on the registration page). I've looked at adding user profile fields but I want the information to be isolated from their profile information, in whatever way works. Can anyone recommend any plugins or ways for doing this.

Also, when the user wants to edit this information - I do not want it to be displayed next to miscellaneous account details.

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. If you are interested in custom solution please show what you have working already and what specific details you have trouble achieving.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/). I think that has some of the community/profile aspects you are looking for.